# Why is this javascript snippet logging 1?

Tags: javascript

In an interview, I was asked to guess the output of the following snippet:

```js
var foo = 1;
    
function bar() {
    foo = 10;
    return;
    function foo() {
    }
}

bar();

console.log(foo);
```

and I thought the output will be 10 because the bar function returns right after reassigning the value of foo but the actual output is 1. Is it because of the function definition with the same variable name(foo)? Is a new scope created for the `foo` variable inside `bar`?

Comment: because `foo` in `bar()` is defined function, not variable from parent scope

Comment: `foo` as the name of the local function is hoisted and overrides the `var foo` in the higher scope

Comment: You are right. You've redefined `foo` in local scope of function. As long as there is any definition inside of function scope - the global one won't be affected.

Comment: The output could be `10`. Cant say for certain by just *seeing* the code. `"fоo" === "foo"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a nasty (and somewhat pointless) question to ask in an interview!

It is indeed got to do with the function `foo` in the scope of `bar` - without that it does what you would have expected.

```js
 var foo = 1;
    
function bar() {
    foo = 10;
    return;
    
}

bar();

console.log(foo);
```

The reason is due to "hoisting" - the function declaration within `bar` gets hoisted to the start of the function `bar` as a new variable, and due to the nature of javascript letting you change the type at runtime, it allows you to set it (and not the global) `foo` to 10.

It is essentially the same as this code:

```js
 var foo = 1;
    
function bar() {
    var foo;
    foo = 10;
}

bar();

console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 3):

The function declaration inside `bar` creates a new local name `foo`, which shadows the outer one. Essentially the `function foo() {}` line is hoisted to the top of the function. You can see this here:

```js
function bar() {
    console.log(foo);
    foo = 10;
    console.log(foo);
    return;
    function foo() {}
}

bar();
```

So `foo = 10` modifies the local `foo` name, not the global one.